# Writing a method isAbleToFly(), which takes no argument and returns true or false?

Tags: java, methods, interface, boolean

I am writing an interface called Launchable. The Launchable interface specifies three methods: launch(), which takes no argument and returns no value, isAbleToFly(), which takes no argument and returns true or false, and land() which takes no argument and returns no value.

this is what I have attempted for the isAbleToFly:

```
 public interface Launchable
{
 public void launch();

 public boolean isAbleToFly();
 return true

 public void land();

 }
```

but it says illegal start of type return true?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your attempted logic is: "Are you able to fly?" "If then yes. Otherwise no.", can you spot the logic error?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: @Smile  The Launchable interface specifies three methods: launch(), which takes no argument and returns no value, isAbleToFly(), which takes no argument and returns true or false, and land() which takes no argument and returns no value.

    i.Write the Launchable interface.

Comment: @Kayaman please look at updated code

Comment: @Haroon1234567 now you changed things randomly, hoping it would work. Programming isn't that easy. Start here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ besides, interfaces don't have implementation at all.

Answer (score 1):

`boolean isAbleToFly()` looks fine as the interface declaration, but you probably do not want to declare the implementation in the interface (`return true`). If you are using Java 8 or higher, you can declare a default implementation for your method (more info bellow).

You will need to create a class that extends that interface and only then add the implementation. 
If you want a structure where you define a contract for certain methods while implementing others, take a look at abstract classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

```java
    interface Launchable {
         void launch();

         boolean isAbleToFly();

         void land();
     }

     class LandThing implements Launchable {
         public void launch() {
             System.out.println("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯");
         }

         public boolean isAbleToFly() {
             return false;
         }

         public void land() {
            System.out.println("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"); 
         }

     }

    class Playground {
        public static void main(String[ ] args) {
            Launchable landThing = new LandThing();
            System.out.println("Can landThing fly?: " + landThing.isAbleToFly());
            landThing.land();
        }
    }
```

Runnable example [here](https://code.sololearn.com/cd241u1l3F2c)

==== Edit about default methods in interfaces ===

As for Java 8 or higher, now you can declare [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) for your interfaces, as in the [following example](https://code.sololearn.com/cfDVn9ZcciYU). According to the docs, the use case is to provide backwards compatibility for older code when you evolve the interface, so it might not be what you are looking for.

```java
    interface Launchable {
         void launch();

         default boolean isAbleToFly() {
             return true;
         };

         void land();
     }

     class FlyThing implements Launchable {
         public void launch() {
             System.out.println("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯");
         }

         // Notice that we will be using the default implementation of isAbleToFly here


         public void land() {
            System.out.println("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"); 
         }

     }


     class LandThing implements Launchable {
         public void launch() {
             System.out.println("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯");
         }

         public boolean isAbleToFly() {
             return false;
         }

         public void land() {
            System.out.println("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"); 
         }

     }

    class Playground {
        public static void main(String[ ] args) {
            Launchable landThing = new LandThing();
            Launchable flyThing = new FlyThing();
            System.out.println("Can landThing fly?: " + landThing.isAbleToFly());
            System.out.println("Can flyThing fly?: " + flyThing.isAbleToFly());

            landThing.land();
        }
    }
```